# SalesforceIQ and Outlook - Always On?

Tags: outlook

Is there any way to keep SalesforceIQ always on in an Outlook Integration?

Right now my users thrilled with the Outlook SalesforceIQ integration. It appears each time you reply or launch an email you must launch inbox which takes 5-40 seconds.  That is too much overhead for every email.  If you don't Launch Inbox for composing an email you will not get read receipts. Am I missing something?